# Manual install of pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, pyodbc

This is for a Windows machine.
Can I just copy over the `pyodbc` in my site-packages library to be able to use it?

`pyodbc.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`
`pyodbc-4.0.16-py3.6.egg-info`

Reason is the machine cannot connect to the internet. Thus, I cannot use `pip` to install directly.

Alternatively, I have a folder `pyodbc-4.0.17` locally which has the `setup.py`. Will I be able to install it manually and how to skip any dependencies, if any, as it will also try to connect to the net if I'm correct.

Please let me know if there is any other way.

Answer (score 4):

Better download `pyodbc-4.0.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/4.0.17), move to the machine and install with `pip`:

```
pip install pyodbc-4.0.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Btw, do you know which folder(s) it creates once installed in the site-packages?

Comment: Probably `pyodbc`. But you don't need to know this. If the imports works all is fine.